# Contours -- OpenCV error : Same output for different features like Hull, Rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, contour

Image used --

[image]

My code:

```
# multiple programs

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Dodo.jpg', 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print(M)

cx = int(M['m10']/ M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/ M['m00'])
print("Cx:", cx, "Cy:", cy)

area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
print("Area:", area)
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
print("Perimeter:", perimeter)

epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
imgapprox = cv2.drawContours(img,[approx],0,(0,0,255),2)

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
imghull =cv2.drawContours(img,[hull],0,(0,0,255),2)

k = cv2.isContourConvex(cnt)
print(k)

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
rectst = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)


rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
rectrt =cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('StraightRect', rectst)
cv2.imshow('RotatedRect', rectrt)
cv2.imshow('Approx', imgapprox)
cv2.imshow('hull', imghull)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

OpenCV-Python version 3.4.1

So I am trying to learn the contour section in OpenCV (Link below)

Link : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Now the output is the same for all the features. i.e. same output for every cv2.imshow here.

Why? What is the error?
If it is overwriting the previous feature, then how do I display every feature?

Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the change in the same image each time. 
Use image.copy() in `cv2.drawContours(img.copy ,.......)` , `cv2.rectangle(img.copy(),.....)`
.Because of that it seems they are showing the same features but it isn't . 
Also since the background is black you are not able to see the rectangles and contour properly

Try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Dodo.jpg')

f1 = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
f1 = cv2.threshold(f1, 120,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(f1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
#img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print(M)

cx = int(M['m10']/ M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/ M['m00'])
print("Cx:", cx, "Cy:", cy)

area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
print("Area:", area)
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
print("Perimeter:", perimeter)

epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
imgapprox = cv2.drawContours(img.copy(),[approx],0,(0,0,255),2)

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
imghull =cv2.drawContours(img.copy(),[hull],0,(0,0,255),2)

k = cv2.isContourConvex(cnt)
print(k)

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
rectst = cv2.rectangle(img.copy(),(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)


rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
rectrt =cv2.drawContours(img.copy(),[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('StraightRect', rectst)
cv2.imshow('RotatedRect', rectrt)
cv2.imshow('Approx', imgapprox)
cv2.imshow('hull', imghull)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**This is the result i get after executing the above code.**
[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the best way to answer a question i.e. with the implementation of the solution in the code. Whoever reads this solution, please learn from him.

Comment: Hey, you said since the background is black I am having difficulties in observing the contours. But if you see in the documentation(link below), you find the line that says In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black background. So remember, object to be found should be white and background should be black.

Link : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Try the basic apple (foreground : white)  with black background image and you could see everything properly.

Comment: That black and white image is a binary image . And to draw contour , use rgb/bgr format to see the lines and bounding box.
`img1 = cv2.imread('Dodo.jpg')`  this one gives you image in bgr format
`img = cv2.imread('Dodo.jpg', 0)` this one is grayscale . You cant see coloured lines in grayscale.

Comment: I didn't get you . Another comment? where?

Comment: Read my first comment again. I posted something else before (to which you answered by the time I deleted it as I understood the answer.) So read it again it's been modified. 
I said I could see the contours and rectangles properly in the thresholded black and white apple image. (idk how to post that image through comments)
path : opencv/samples/data/shape_sample/1.png